# WSO2-IS 5.10.0 - Tenant ID cannot be -1 - External Ldap

Tags: openldap, wso2-identity-server

I have configured an external ldap and created an user "ainacio@wso2.com" in identity server and now I can't sign in to identity server using this user. I've gived all permissions to this user.

deployment.toml

```
[embedded_ldap]
enable = false

[user_store]
type = "read_write_ldap"
connection_url = "ldap://cup-openldap:389"
connection_name = "cn=admin,dc=close-upinternational,dc=com"
connection_password = "####"
....
```

WSO2-IS log:

```
is-as-km_1| WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.util.AnonymousSessionUtil} - Failed to retrieve Realm for the Invalid Domain : wso2.com
is-as-km_1| ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} - Invalid domain or unactivated tenant login
is-as-km_1| ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient} - Error occurred while logging in java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tenant ID cannot be -1
```

**I can see the user created in indentiy server on ldap server but I cannot sign-in :(.**

Comment: Is that user's username is `ainacio@wso2.com` and he is in the carbon.super tenant? or else is that the user's name is `ainacio` and he is in `wso2.com` tenant?

Comment: Username is ainacio@wso2.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to enable tenant to use email domain on deployment.toml:

```
[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true
```